# configMap values are not injected to springboot app after using k8s hostNetwork flag

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

I am trying to use "hostNetwork" flag to make my POD communicating over the node's network interface. But after adding this flag the config is not injected from the configmap but the default values from "application.properties" are used instead. Is that expected behavior ?

Note: when I remove the "hostNetwok" flag the app values are injected from the configmap.

I am working on kubernetes V 1.19.

deployment.yaml :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dummy-service-deployment
  labels:
    app: dummy-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dummy-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dummy-service
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      containers:
      - name: dummy-service
        image: dummyService:2.10.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
```

bootstrap.yaml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: dummy-service
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      reload:
        enabled: true
        mode: polling
        period: 10000
      config:
        sources:
          - name: dummy-service-cm
```

Many thanks in advance ...

Comment: I wouldn't expect that, but I wouldn't expect pods to specify host networking either, except in some very unusual circumstances.  What are you trying to set up?

Comment: we are using it in a POC to establish a connection between our containers and legacy system over diameter protocol.

Comment: I'd bet $1 that spring-cloud only looks for `kubernetes.default.svc` or the equivalent of `$KUBERNETES_HOST`, neither of which are going to be available without CNI running (q.v. the `hostNetwork` bit); you can either try dialing up the verbosity of spring-cloud and see which it is trying to use, or use [`hostAliases:`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#podspec-v1-core) and/or add a specific `env:` entry that specifies `KUBERNETES_HOST`